# Passing contents of a php variable using the URL

Tags: php, variables, url

I would like to pass the value of a php variable using the URL, by using the variable name. Here is a sample of what I am trying to achieve, it doesn't work, bu also doesn't crash so I know that I am close....anyone...please:

```
<a href="student_what_learning_unit.php?student=<?php $student_user ?>">Unit Learning</a>
```

Comment: Define *it doesn't work*.

Comment: Of course it doesn't work you need to `echo` `$student_user`

Answer (score 1):

Personally I don't like to put little pieces of PHP code inside HTML. It can be done, but it is problematic. Better to write clean PHP code, like:

```
<?php

$url = 'student_what_learning_unit.php?student='.urlencode($student_user);
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Unit Learning</a>';
```

You do need the `urlencode()` for an URL, see:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Thank you, that will sort me out.I agree - mixing php into html and html with parts of php have caused me a headache - but I'm fairly new to php and I would do it differently if I were to start again

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `echo` like this:

```
<a href="student_what_learning_unit.php?student=<?php echo $student_user ?>">Unit Learning</a>
```